# Please help me write a subcript

Tags: formatting

I type `&A_(i1)&, &A_(i2)&,...,&A_(im)&`. I would like `i1` is a subscript of `A` and similar to `i2, ..., im`. But I can do it correct. Please let me know how can I type it and get the correct result. Thanks so much.

Comment: You have to use braces. `A_{i1}`

Comment: You can always search on TEX.SE: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=insert+subscripts

Comment: Don't use `...`. Use `\dots` instead.

Answer (score 3):

It is not entirely clear to me what you desire to achieve, but note that you should use curly brackets `{}` instead of parentheses `()`:

```
$A_{i1}, A_{i2},\dots,A_{im}$
```

will give

[image]

and you include the `&` when in a `tabular` or `align` environment, for example.

If this does not answer your question, please post a [minimum working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Observe that TeX commands are not rendered here. So *will give* has no meaning.

Comment: Don't use `...`. Use `\dots` instead.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Interesting, there are other SE-sites where TeX is rendered, but not on the tex-site.

Comment: Your answer is helpful for a new learner.  I note, though, that `&` would not be used in an `equation` environment, but rather one of the `align` style environments.

Comment: Yes, thank you (Marie. P) for your interesting answer. I do it correctly. And, please let me know why I can't add \begin{definition} ... \end{definition}. It's always errors: "! LaTeX Error: Environment definition undefined.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \begin{definition}" since I started learning Latex for two days.

Comment: For this, you really need to post a MWE in a new question. But the first guess is that you need to make sure that the `definition`-environment is actually defined. Check, for example, this:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Theorems